# Why isnt IBus functional (in Xfce)?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce, ibus

I'm trying to use IBus to type in Japanese. I have set up the Anthy IME properly, and the "enable or disable" setting to function when pressing ctrl+space.

In any case, it's simply not working.

I enter the keyboard combination, and the input method just doesn't switch on. Specifically clicking on "Japanese - Anthy" doesn't do anything either; it stays on "Input Method Off".

I'm using Xfce on Xubuntu 12.10

Installed IBus-related packages:

```
gir1.2-ibus-1.0
ibus    
ibus-anthy
ibus-clutter:i386
ibus-gtk:i386
ibus-gtk3:i386
ibus-mozc
ibus-qt4
ibus-table
ibus-xkbc
libibus-1.0-0:i386
libibus-qt1
libusb-0.1-4:i386
libusb-1.0-0:i386
libusbmuxd2
python-ibus
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to open "input method switcher" in the xfce configuration tool and select ibus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried that already. Didn't work. Later, however, I tried using mozc for the input method, and surprisingly, it works without issue. Anthy problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself, but it was by not using Anthy.

If IBus fails to work when using Anthy, try the mozc input method instead (available in the package repo as ibus-mozc). Or try something alternative for whatever language input method you were trying.